# Dropdown menus on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

So I have some dropdown menus, and I listen for the `touchstart` event to show them, but the problem is that I don't know when to close them, since I have 2 dropdown menus on the page the problem is that..if a user clicks on a dropdown menu and I display it and after that clicks on another...that gets displayed to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav ul li.sub-menu > a,nav ul li.sub-menu2 > a').bind( "touchstart",function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
        $(this).parent().addClass('active_page');
    });
});
```

Any ideas how to close it, when it's best to close it? :-?

Comment: Deal with touches just like clicks - if a user clicks on a menu item, open it. If they click on another menu, close the open one and open the second.

Comment: And how should I do that? can you give a code snippet or something?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add an overlay div with position absolute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('nav ul li.sub-menu > a,nav ul li.sub-menu2 > a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
        $('body').prepend('<div class="overlay" />');
        $('.overlay').css({'width' : $('body').css('width'), 'height' : $('body').css('height')});
        $(this).parent().addClass('active_page');

        return false;
    });


    $('.overlay').live('touchstart',function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $('.drop').each(function(){
            if($(this).find('ul').css('display') == 'block')
            {
                $(this).find('ul').toggle();
            }
        });
        //$('nav ul li.sub-menu2 > ul,nav ul li.sub-menu > ul').toggle();

        return false;
    });

});
```